# FormGroup Directive error in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

While working on a page in ionic3 I am trying to call a function on click of a icon but I am getting the following error :

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using formGroup's partner directive \"formControlName\" instead.
```

However the issue is that there is no form control involved in the complete HTML file.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div class="row">
    <div col-4>
      <p>Name</p>
    </div>
    <div col-8 style="text-align: right">
      <p>{{profiledetails.firstName}} {{profiledetails.lastName}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" (click)="phoneverify()">
    <div col-4>
      <p>Phone</p>
    </div>
    <div col-8 style="text-align: right">
      <p>{{profiledetails.phoneNo}} &nbsp;&nbsp;<ion-icon name="{{phoneverified}}"></ion-icon></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here `phoneverify()` is the function that needs to implemented but on including this it gives the above error. Unable to figure out the issue.
The code for the `phoneverify()` in the .ts file is as follows

```
phoneverify(){
this.navCtrl.push(Profileverifypage);
}
```

However this Profileverifypage page has a form involved.

Comment: there is no form in your code. post complete code

Comment: This is what I am saying sir that there is no form in my complete code and thats what the issue is all about.

Comment: is there any other page that has a form? Can you post the `phonevevrify()` method or your whole .ts file for this page?